# Кириллица в sublime text 3

Tags: кодировка, sublime-text-3

Может кто подсказать почему при использовании команды Build в Sublime text 3, в консоли кирилица отображается некорректно - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дело в том что ты наверно используешь билдер который скачал через **Package Control** у меня через него тоже не отображает, напиши свой...

**Tools > Build System > New Build System**

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "node \"${file}\""
}
```

сохраняешь и все работает

---

[image: пример работы]